# Discord.py kick command not working with no error message

Tags: python, discord.py, pycord

This kick command worked, but after adding an embed it doesn't. Any idea why?

```py
#KICK COMMAND
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, user : discord.Member,*,reason):
  
  kickbed = discord.Embed(title="Kick Log",description=f"Kicked by {ctx.author}.", color=23457535)
 
  kickbed.add_field(name="User Kicked:", value=f'{user}',inline=False)
 
  kickbed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f'{Reason}',inline=False)
  
  await user.kick(reason=reason)
  await ctx.send(embed=kickbed)
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you used variable `reason`, but then in:

```py
kickbed.add_field(name="Reason:", value=f'{Reason}',inline=False)
```

You used the variable `Reason` (uppercase first letter), which is not defined. You just have to change it to `reason`.

Then you used `23457535` as a color, which is incorrect because the value you pass to the `color=` should be less than or equal to `16777215`.

[discord.Colour in docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Colour)

---

As stated by [@NikkieDev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70294780/14048071):

> *It could be because you're trying to mention a user that is not in the server.*

When I tested it works (mentioning while a user is not on the server), but if you want you could send the message first and then kick the user:

```py
await ctx.send(embed=kickbed) # changed the order of last 2 lines
await user.kick(reason=reason)
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be because you're trying to mention a user that is not in the server. Therefore it cannot mention the user.

Try this instead:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
    async def kick(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, reason="No reason given"):
        kickDM=discord.Embed(title='Kicked', description=(f"You've been kicked from {member.guild.name} for {reason} by {ctx.author}"))
        kickMSG=discord.Embed(title='Kicked', description=(f"{member} has been kicked from {member.guild.name} for {reason} by {ctx.author}"))
        await member.send(embed=kickDM)
        await ctx.send(embed=kickMSG)
        await member.kick(reason=reason)
bot.add_command(kick)
```

Comment: OP is not mentioning a user. When a `discord.User` or `discord.Member` object is converted to a string, you get `<username>#<discriminator>`.

Comment: Also, you can mention users who are outside of the server you are sending the message in.